# Deleting large number of files

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script to delete large number of files in linux. The script will run every two minutes in crontab. I tried using the
 `find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -name "*.pcap" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lt | tail -$del | awk '{print $8}'`

and saving this to a variable and tried to delete using `rm`  command, but dint run. I have found out that `find . -type f -delete`   can be used to delete the files, but I don't know how to add this part to my command. How would I do this?

Comment: FWIW there is a Unix-based Stack Exchange: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how large the number is? reaches 100k level? This is important, because, you may face IO bottleneck problem. Many years ago I had experience to remove 2m small files from some dir.

Comment: off-topic should be on: http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: The files are around 50000..

Comment: Are you deleting files ove a `/mnt` point? Does this mean the files are on a different machine?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `-print0` with `-delete`:

```
find /mnt/md0/capture/DCN/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.pcap" -delete
```